# Grep does not always find the correct value from a file

Tags: shell, awk, grep, cut

I am trying to extract two `#define` values from a `C` header file to use them in a shell script. So I use grep to find them and then print them. However, the variables are sometimes empty.

```
// main.h
#define DEVICE_NO 1
#define FW_VERSION 1
```

And the script file is

```
#!/bin/bash - 
read_version()
{
  echo $(grep $1 "$projectdir/Inc/main.h" | cut -d ' ' -f 3-)
}

device_no=$(read_version "DEVICE_NO")
fw_version=$(read_version "FW_VERSION")
echo "DEVICE_NO = $device_no, FW_VERSION = $fw_version"
```

So the expectation is that the output to be:

```
DEVICE_NO = 1, FW_VERSION = 1
```

but sometimes it turns to be

```
5
DEVICE_NO = , FW_VERSION = 1
```

It randomly misses one or both of the values. The header file does not change so it's not coming from there.

**UPDATE**

As commented I thought maybe the windows line ending is a problem so I piped the output to `tr` and removed `\r` but it did not make any difference. also tried `var=$(grep FW_VERSION file); $(echo ${var//[$'\t\r\n']} | cut ...` to no avail.

I tried using awk instead of cut but got the same result.

I redirected the error inside the command to the standard output (`$(grep $1 file | cut -d ' ' -f 3 2>&1)` but did not get any extra information

I split the command to a `grep` part and a `cut`, the `grep` never misses but the output of `cut` randomly gives an empty string as output.

I still have no idea where that `5` is coming from, there is nothing in `cut` or `awk` manuals that throws a `5` to either standard output or stderr.

Comment: You're using quotes exactly wrong.  Instead of `read_version "DEVICE_NO"`, you could safely write `read_version DEVICE_NO` (but there no reason not to use quotes here).  But in the function you must quote `$1` (eg `grep "$1" "$projectdir/Inc/main.h"` ).  Literal strings do not need to be quoted.  Strings that will include a variable interpolation must be quoted. (generally)

Comment: Does the header file have regular unix newlines?  given that the 5 is printed before the DEVICE_NO = line, it feels like a race condition and somehow perhaps the output of `cut` is going to stderr. Can you pipe the output to a hex dump and verify that there are no `\r` in the output?  This behavior is strange.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for the input. I updated the script based on your first comment and it wasn't the problem (I guess just best practices). I'm using eclipse in windows and this script is post-built so you are correct, the line ending has `\r`. If that's the problem, why does it randomly work?